# How to open new window when click on button or link using javascript in BPM 8.5.5.0

Tags: javascript, business-process-management, new-window

How can I achieve opening a coach in a new window in IBM BPM 8.5.5.0? For example, I have two coaches in an human service, when I click a button/link on the first coach, the another coach will be opened in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the standard Human service behavior as by default, the second coach will replace the first.
You have two options and the correct approach will depend on your scenario:

1. Use a modal rather than a second coach.
2. Put the second coach in a separate service and mark it as an ajax service. You can them simply call the URL for the second coach from a button or link on the first coach and display it in a new tab or window.

Comment: thanks Harely for the given answer, I have one doubt, is it possible to do in IBM BPM 8.5.5.0 ?

Comment: Harley can you tell me the steps for the second scenario.how to give URL in ajax service

Comment: Hi, this article should give you everything you need:
http://www.ibpmcoding.com/2013/03/invoking-rest-api-from-external-system.html